# Why is Node.js crypto.sign function non-deterministic?

Tags: node.js, sign, elliptic-curve

I have the following piece of Node.js code:

```
let jwktopem = require('jwk-to-pem');
let crypto = require('crypto');

let key = jwktopem({
    crv: 'P-256',
    kty: 'EC',
    use: 'sig',
    x: Buffer.from('8E54B421A5B51D7A5089D69E140B9ABA3FF46D9E0F16614F9A658E49E584F539', 'hex').toString('base64'),
    y: Buffer.from('BB20BECA0B53E6CF3263226E056A0F77050AB428C10EB3B2B7E92E5D7328FC7E', 'hex').toString('base64'),
    d: Buffer.from('9963F284D16B0096F40A6153895903CAF60EEB3CA90EA4FC6AAD3512486E9790', 'hex').toString('base64'),
    kid: '1'
}, {private: true})
let message = Buffer.from('oSThaT8Kriu5Pzey6bQgCd/Ynwtpxl1PLeE+0i751Ok=', 'base64');

function signIt() {
    const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
    sign.update(message);    
    console.log(sign.sign(key, 'hex'));
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    signIt();
}
```

I'm basically signing the same message with the same key 10 times, using Elliptic Curve cryptography. But I get 10 different results! What is going on here?

Comment: Perhaps because there's a timestamp included in the signature? That does not necessarily make it non-deterministic.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this timestamp?

Comment: With different timestamp, you get different results. And timestamp is the current UNIX time. So every second it changes :D

Comment: But anyway, I don't see timestamp here.

Comment: I know what a timestamp is. What I want to know is where it is in the signature.

Comment: Update your question with the output and perhaps someone can identify if there is a timestamp in it.

Comment: The source is [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_crypto.cc):  After a quick skim over `Sign::` methods, I don't see where it's using time but I don't know cryptography all that well.

Comment: We've been checking the C++ Sign source code and it's a mess. We just assumed they add some kind of salt.

Answer (score 0):

The ECDSA signature algorithm involves the random number for exactly this purpose, generate unique non-reversible signature. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm

The quality of random is vital for the security of the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Having or not determinsm in the signature depends on an in-process value "k" generated during the execution of the ECDSA algorithm. I assume that in your case nodejs is using a random value for "k" thus generating a different signature. There are other cases where the value of "k" is deterministic by following [RFC-6979](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6979#section-3.2) as explained [here](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-messages)